# Where have the Gmail API Snippets Gone?

Tags: gmail-api

Here is a screenshot from a [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjEPiWf0BWg) video that shows some really useful PHP Google API snippets. For some reason Google seems to have removed them. Does anybody know where they have gone?

[image: Screenshot From Video Showing API Snippets]

Comment: Im not sure i understand the question can you be more clear as to your question.  Adding your code and describing the error would be of help.

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks for the speedy reply. If you take a look at the screenshot above you will see that the documentation used to have PHP code snippets. If you take a look at the current documentation you will the snippets have been removed. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list. I'm trying to find out where they have gone.

Comment: Google does not supply snippets for every method in every language, parameter or API.  [Google API php samples](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples)  I have some that might help you though.

Comment: @DaImTo Wow! That's quite a repository you have compiled there. Many thanks. I'll take a look later today. I can't understand why Google have removed the snippets in the example above though. Documentation usually gets better - not worse.

Comment: The probably is then they need to keep it updated to the latest version of a language and they rarely want to bother doing that.  Which is why i have been generating samples snippets myself..

Comment: @DaImTo You're doing a great job. Many thanks.

Comment: While I'm no longer on the team, my guess is that they're shorthanded & can't support samples in all languages as Linda alluded to. However, the PHP Quickstart is still there http://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php plus the full PHP reference http://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/php/latest/ ... also, all of the PHP G Suite/Google Workspace samples that *are* supported can be found at http://github.com/googleworkspace/php-samples

Comment: @wescpy Thanks for getting back to me. The old snippets were a great starting point and I feel the documentation has definitely taken a backward step by taking them out. Even if they weren't maintained, I would still rather they were there. Who would be a good person to contact about this matter?

Comment: People rotate, so there isn't any one person, but reach out privately, and we'll see what we can do. Another thing you can do is to click on "Send feedback" in the upper-right. You can screenshot with the tool & indicate what's wrong.